# box-plot for multiple columns with normalized x-axis values

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, boxplot

I have the following data (in csv file)

```
 product release_after_issue  release_before_issue
 P1                           40
 P1      100    
 P1                           10
 P2      50
 P2      300
 P2                           200
 P3      10
 P3      20
 P3      300
```

I would like use the box-plot to show the distribution of days for each product release (P1, P2, etc.) based on `release_after_issue` and `release_before_issue`. The x-axis is the products names and y-axis is days.

The issues that I am facing now are:the empty values in each column, and the big number for the days.

How could I normalize the days in y-axis to be in month (easy to read)? And I wold like to have each product (Ps) has its own box plot based on the column's data (`release_after_issue`  or `release_before_issue`)

I tried to omit NA values and plot test example, but it did not work

```
data <- read.csv("commons-fileupload.csv")
    ggplot(data[!is.na(data$release_after_issue),],aes(x=product,y=release_after_issue))
    + geom_point()
```

Any help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what fails in your code, the dummy data below works fine for me. 
Also, ggplot removes the NAs for you.

```
data <- data.frame(product=c("P1","P2","P1","P1","P2"),release_after_issue=c(100,NA,50,10,30))
ggplot(data,aes(x=product,y=release_after_issue))+ geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Comment: It is working, without the condition that I used in my question. Thank you for that help. How to normalize the days in y-axis to months? any idea?

Comment: Is that what you are trying to get?

ggplot(data,aes(x=product,y=round(release_after_issue/30,0)))+ geom_boxplot()+labs(y="months")

Comment: it gives an error? Error: unexpected input in "ggplot(data,aes(x=product,y=round(release_after_issue/30,0))\"

Comment: it's because when copy/pasting the code, characters get inserted (between the brackets I believe). 
Make sure the formula you have in R looks like what I wrote, without any added characters.

ggplot(data,aes(x=product,y=round(release_after_issue/30,0))‌​)+
geom_boxplot()+labs(y="months")

Comment: I fixed the issue !!
as you mentioned , some of the special character get inserted and rewrite the scrip from the beginning with clean code. It is working now. thank you